# sorting a 2d array by one row

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a really specified problem to deal with. I need to descending  sort an array[4][x]. 
From instance if i get values like:

```
{121,120,203,240}
{0.5,0.2,3.2,1.4}
{1.3,1.5,1.2,1.8}
{3  ,2  ,5  ,4  }
```

**All values have to bo sorted by the 4th row**. Thus, I need an output like this:

```
{203,240,121,120}
{3.2,1.4,0.5,0.2}
{1.2,1.8,1.3,1.5}
{5  ,4  ,3  ,2  }
```

I have tried doing it by the bubble sort method, but it does not work properly.

Comment: How did bubble sort not work properly? What behavior did you observe and how did that differ from expectations? Please show what you've done. Ideally, provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Mateusz Staniaszek  This {2  ,3  ,4  ,5  } is the ascending sort, is not it?

Comment: Oh my fault, i have to correct it above. I thought about descending.

Comment: "I have tried doing it by the bubble sort method" --> post your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [help] and [ask].

Comment: I'm surprised C++ doesn't yet have a default algorithm to do this kind of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach of sorting the array using the bubble sort can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4;

    double a[][N] =
    {
        { 121, 120, 203, 240 },
        { 0.5, 0.2, 3.2, 1.4 },
        { 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.8 },
        { 3, 2, 5, 4 }
    };

    for (const auto &row : a)
    {
        for (double x : row) std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //  The bubble sort
    for (size_t n = N, last = N; not (n < 2); n = last)
    {
        for (size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[N - 1][i - 1] < a[N - 1][i])
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    std::swap(a[j][i - 1], a[j][i]);
                }
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (const auto &row : a)
    {
        for (double x : row) std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
121 120 203 240
0.5 0.2 3.2 1.4
1.3 1.5 1.2 1.8
  3   2   5   4

203 240 121 120
3.2 1.4 0.5 0.2
1.2 1.8 1.3 1.5
  5   4   3   2
```

All you need is to extract the code of the bubble sort from main and rewrite it as a separate function for any 2D array and any row used as the criteria of sorting.

Comment: That's not very efficient. I'd introduce an array of pairs (4th row value, index), quicksort that, and then rearrange the array according to the indices of the sorted pairs.

Comment: @Michael Creating an array of an arbitrary size is already inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be easy to solve if instead of parallel vectors we had a structure containing parallel values.

It is easy enough to get back to such a structure: just create some intermediate vector containing sort keys and indexes and sort it.

After sorting the indexes are giving us a direct way to reorder all the individual vectors in the right order.

I would  do something like below (I put it in a Boost Unit Test, but what is done should be obvious) .

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestPenta
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> v1 = {121,120,203,240};
std::vector<float> v2 = {0.5,0.2,3.2,1.4};
std::vector<float> v3 = {1.3,1.5,1.2,1.8};
std::vector<int> v4 = {3  ,2  ,5  ,4  };

std::vector<int> expected_v1 = {203,240,121,120};
std::vector<float> expected_v2 = {3.2,1.4,0.5,0.2};
std::vector<float> expected_v3 = {1.2,1.8,1.3,1.5};
std::vector<int> expected_v4 = {5  ,4  ,3  ,2  };

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestFailing)
{
    // First create an index to sort containing sort key and initial position
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vindex{};
    int i = 0;
    for (auto x: v4){
        vindex.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(x,i));
        ++i;
    }

    // Sort the index vector by key value
    struct CmpIndex {
        bool operator() (std::pair<int, int> & a, std::pair<int, int> & b) { 
            return a.first > b.first ;
        }
    } cmp;

    std::sort(vindex.begin(), vindex.end(), cmp);

    // Now reorder all the parallel vectors using index
    // (of course in actual code we would write some loop if several vector are of the same type).
   // I'm using parallel loops to avoid using too much memory for intermediate vectors

    {
        std::vector<int> r1;
        for (auto & p: vindex){
            r1.push_back(v1[p.second]);
        }
        v1 = r1;
    }
    {
        std::vector<float> r2;
        for (auto & p: vindex){
            r2.push_back(v2[p.second]);
        }
        v2 = r2;
    }
    {
        std::vector<float> r3;
        for (auto & p: vindex){
            r3.push_back(v3[p.second]);
        }
        v3 = r3;
    }
    {
        std::vector<int> r4;
        for (auto & p: vindex){
            r4.push_back(v4[p.second]);
        }
        v4 = r4;
    }

    // Et voila! The vectors are all sorted as expected
    i = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i){
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected_v1[i], v1[i]);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected_v2[i], v2[i]);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected_v3[i], v3[i]);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected_v4[i], v4[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```